# How to make baseline visible?

Tags: baseline, box

I found this nice page with notes on LaTeX: https://unix4lyfe.org/tex-notes/#entry26

It gives this sample code:

```
\def\vhb#1{\vbox{\hbox{#1}}}

A vbox:
\vbox{\vhb{eight}\vhb{gnat}}
and a vtop:
\vtop{\vhb{eight}\vhb{gnat}}
on one line.
```

And also provides the output of this code "with visible boxes and baselines":
[image]

How can I achieve the exact output? I found no way to make baselines and boxes visible.

**EDIT: I am using `pdflatex` which I'd like to keep.**

Answer (score 4):

ConTeXt has the built-in command `\showboxes` which does what you want.

```
\showboxes
\starttext

\def\vhb#1{\vbox{\hbox{#1}}}

A vbox:
\vbox{\vhb{eight}\vhb{gnat}}
and a vtop:
\vtop{\vhb{eight}\vhb{gnat}}
on one line.

\stoptext
```

[image]

A similar thing is available with LuaLaTeX in the [`lua-visual-debug`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}

\def\vhb#1{\vbox{\hbox{#1}}}

A vbox:
\vbox{\vhb{eight}\vhb{gnat}}
and a vtop:
\vtop{\vhb{eight}\vhb{gnat}}
on one line.

\end{document}
```

[image]