# How to make baselines visible?

Tags: baseline

I want to show all baselines in all pages of my documentation.

This question has been discussed in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422506/how-to-make-baseline-visible), but the solutions provided don't work at all. I'm using pdflatex.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no standard way to do this in pdflatex (in luatex there is for example lua-visual-debug package, so you could consider using luatex if only for this) In controlled environments where you have good advance knowledge of the spacing you can overlay some rules with the correct spacing, but in general it is rather hard to do this.

Comment: could you clarify if you want to draw a "target baseline" eg a page with lines every 15pt, over which you typeset the text (that is relatively easy)  or visually show the actual baselines used by TeX after they have been adjusted for variable sized displays or over-large inline math etc, that is hard-to-impossible in pdftex depending ho general your document text is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! I want to visually show the actual baselines used by TeX after they have been adjusted, but it seems difficult in pdftex like that you commented.

Comment: actually it is impossible by design to access that information within tex, so "difficult" isn't putting it strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `\interlinepenalty` and some other penalties to a high negative value and let the output routine draw the baselines. The following example is not perfect and has some bugs but it could be a starting point.

The basic idea is taken from there:
http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91pearls.pdf

```
\def\showbaseline{\hbox to\wd0{\setbox0=\hbox to\wd0{\unhbox0}%
        \unhbox0 \llap{\vrule height.5pt depth0pt width\hsize}}}
\let\PAR\par
\def\par{\penalty-50000\PAR}% Horrible! Will not work with LaTeX.

% Force the output routine between lines
\predisplaypenalty=-50000
\postdisplaypenalty=-50000
\interdisplaylinepenalty=-50000
\interlinepenalty=-50000
\maxdeadcycles=500% Alsmost every line adds a dead cycle.

\newtoks\orioutput \orioutput=\output % wrap the original \output routine
\output{%
    \ifnum\outputpenalty>-20001 \the\orioutput
    \else\ifnum\outputpenalty<-\maxdimen \the\orioutput
    \else
    \unvbox255        % flush the entire list back
    \setbox0=\lastbox % strip the very last box
    \nointerlineskip  % avoid doubled interline glue
    \showbaseline            % make the test and return the box back.
    \advance\outputpenalty by 50000%
    \penalty\outputpenalty % weak lie that nothing happened...
    \fi\fi}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero $\displaystyle\int$ eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet.
$$ \displaylines{\int \cr  \oint} $$
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
$\displaystyle\int$ sed diam voluptua.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.

\bye
```

[image]